# Github like routes

Tags: url, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

How is this achievable in asp.net mvc? I have seen some ruby examples out there...

[Github like routes in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161582/github-like-routes-in-rails)

i.e. nested folders, can be unlimited... however they are usually nested once

e.g.

lets say my main route in my app is:

/projects/{projectid}/

I am hooked into a file system, so I want users to navigate through whatever directory structure so I can have:

```
/projects/{projectid}/foldera/
/projects/{projectid}/folderb/
/projects/{projectid}/foldera/pic1.png
/projects/{projectid}/folderb/special/car134d.jpeg
```

etc...

This way I can only show files or pictures that are inside the url/directory the user is in...

Comment: What are you actually asking? More details please - a link isn't really enough.

Comment: @MattGibson: when I said *nested* folders I thought that was very clear but it was not, sorry about that.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your edit, as I originally misinterpreted your question to mean something else!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're after is the `{*queryvalues}` [segmented url handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#handling_a_variable_number_of_segments_in_a_url_pattern) for routing. The * indicates a wildcard-style match of one or more segments, delimited by a "/".

To map to a physical path, you can use this to add a route to your Global.asax.cs:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
            "Projects", // Route name
            "projects/{projectId}/{*path}", // Route url format
            "~/ProjectFolder/{projectId}/{path}" // Path to files
            );
```

If you want to get the path into an MVC Controller Action and then do something with it, you could use MapRoute:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Projects", // Route name
            "projects/{projectId}/{*path}", // Route url format
            new { controller = "Project", action = "Index" } // Defaults
            );
```

Then create a `ProjectController`, and in the `Index` action retrieve  `RouteData.Values["projectId"]` and `RouteData.Values["path"]` and do whatever you need to with them...

Comment: The problem is - my file path is in the cloud and not a local directory... Am I assuming that maproute would then be most suited?

Comment: @Haroon, have updated my answer with an example of MapRoute - you'd use MapRoute when you want the incoming request to be picked up by a RouteHandler (such as an MVC Controller/Action), and MapPageRoute for a physical location (Webforms or direct resource mapping)

Comment: thank you... I am going to look into this tomorrow, it looks like the only approach to me, I hope its ok with you if I accept this after I look into it tomorrow